# Visual Studio 2012: LNK2028 and LNK2019 build errors

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors, voxel

I'm getting two errors and cannot figure out how to resolve, here they are:

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0003A0) "void __cdecl polygon(int,int,int,int,unsigned int)" (?polygon@@$$FYAXHHHHI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl vox_texture_cube(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?vox_texture_cube@@$$FYAXII@Z)
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl polygon(int,int,int,int,unsigned int)" (?polygon@@$$FYAXHHHHI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl vox_texture_cube(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?vox_texture_cube@@$$FYAXII@Z)

The only thing I have tried is going into the General Options in the Project properties and changing the Common Language RunTime Support to /clr pure as per another question on here, however, that causes more problems.

Here is my code:

```
//This Function creates a Polygon Face using Vertice Array
//It is the Method for creating each face of a cube
void **polgon**(int a, int b, int c, int d, GLuint texture)         
{
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, whiteSpecularMaterial);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mShininess);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[a]);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[b]);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[c]);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[d]);
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you declare a function called

`void polygon(int a, int b, int c, int d, GLuint texture);`

And then you implement a function called

```
void polgon(int a, int b, int c, int d, GLuint texture)
{
    ...
}
```

So the problem is that the linker is trying to find the function `polygon` which you promised you would implement but didn't.

Solution: Rename `polgon` to `polygon` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Renamed the Function (Silly Error :P) and No Difference in errors i'm afraid

Comment: If you renamed the function then you *must* be getting different errors. Double-check.

Comment: If the code you show here is accurate and if you renamed `polgon` to `polygon`, saved the file and tried to compile again then this error no longer makes sense.

Comment: Hi, I figured the problem. It was because I saved the main .cpp file into another folder for a backup and Visual Studio set it to my main .cpp file. With a simple change it now works :)

Comment: Good to know you got it sorted.